# I am working on a CGI script in Python3 and it recognizes wrong directory

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, cgi

I am working on a CGI script in Python3, but it is referencing the wrong directory. For simplicity, the following works

```
#!/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python3

print ("Content-type:text/html")
print ()                             
print ('<html>')
print ('<head>')
print ('</head>')
print ('<body>')
print ('<h2>Hello Word!</h2>')
print ('</body>')
print ('</html>')
```

But the following does not:

```
#!~/anaconda3/bin/python

print ("Content-type:text/html")
print ()                             
print ('<html>')
print ('<head>')
print ('</head>')
print ('<body>')
print ('<h2>Hello Word!</h2>')
print ('</body>')
print ('</html>')
```

If I try to run this I get a 500 Internal Server Error. The latter is where I actually have my packages stored and execute things from however:

```
which python
~/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Any idea what the problem is? And how I can get CGI to work with the directory I want it to? thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm that the user that runs Apache/NginX/whatever is the same user that has `~/anaconda3/bin/python`?

Comment: Actually, it may be run by root user. How can I change this?

Comment: I think Apache is run by root user and the Python directory is a specific user (/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/python). Any idea what the best solution is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're running a CGI script, you're running it by the same user who is running your server. This will often be, for example, the `www-data` user. This means that `~` is expanded to the `www-data` home directory. If you want to have the CGI script run a specific version of Python, you should put the entire path to the executable after the `#!`.

I highly recommend that you *NOT* try to get Apache or NginX to run as a different user. That can cause unexpected results and more difficulties down the road. It is better to simply use the full path or rely on something already in the ENV.

Comment: Thanks @cwallenpoole! I have edited my setup to use #!/usr/bin/python3 but I am now unable to import modules which should be in my sys.path - new question posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059247/cgi-unable-to-import-module-python3. Any chance you can help there too?

Comment: Also for this particular issue, if I put in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/python3 I still get the same error

Comment: If you're using a virtualenv, have you included this at the beginning of the script? `activator = '{path-to-virtualenv}/bin/activate_this.py';
exec(open(activator).read(), {'__file__': activator})`

Comment: @JonasW. I transitioned from `www.allen-poole.com` to `allen-poole.com` at the same time I transitioned from WordPress to Puput. Forgot to make that update in my profile.